# Postgres: synchronize logical replication between old and new instance (LSN)

Tags: postgresql

Creating a new Postgres instance in AWS RDS using a snapshot of an existing instance, and then trying to set up logical replication between old and new. [This article](https://www.percona.com/blog/postgresql-logical-replication-using-an-rds-snapshot/) says to get the LSN from the latest server log after creation, but no LSN is printed out after the target server is started (I checked all log files). How can I retrieve the correct LSN from a running instance (the target)? The target is unchanged since creation.

Postgres version is 10.21.

Comment: Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70165774/6464308).

Comment: So I HAVE to use pg_dump? There's no way to do it with an AWS snapshot? That would suck for multi-terabyte databases.

Comment: You can use any method that allows you to import a snapshot to control which data are copied. I don't believe an AWS snapshot will do that, although I don't know what that is.